# How to read data from a textfile and add it to a linked list

Tags: java, io, linked-list

I am trying to make a program that holds a list of patients for a hospital.
I'm trying to read data from a textfile and add it to the first node of a linked list.

I'm confused about how I should read the data from the text file and add it to the list.

This is what I have tried so far
My Patient Class:

```
public class Patient implements Serializable {

private String name;
private String patientIDNumber;
private String address;
private int height;
private double weight;


protected LLNode<Patient> head;


public Patient(String n, String ID, String Ad, int h, double w)
{
    name = n;
    patientIDNumber = ID;
    address = Ad;
    height = h;
    weight = w;


}

public String get_name()
{
    return name;
}

public String get_patientIDNumber()
{
    return patientIDNumber;
}

public String get_address()
{
    return address;
}

public int get_height()
{
    return height;
}

public double get_weight()
{
    return weight;
}

public void set_name()
{
    this.name = name;
}

public void set_patientIDNumber()
{
    this.patientIDNumber = patientIDNumber;
}

public void set_address()
{
    this.address = address;
}

public void set_height()
{
    this.height = height;
}

public void set_weight()
{
    this.weight = weight;
}
```

}

my linked list class:

```
public class PatientList<T> implements ListInterface<T>{

protected int numOfElements;
protected LLNode<T> currentPos;
protected boolean found;
protected LLNode<T> location;
protected LLNode<T> previous;

protected LLNode<T> list;
protected LLNode<T> tail;

public PatientList()
{
    numOfElements = 0;
    list = null;
    currentPos = null;
}

public void add(T element)
{
    LLNode<T> newNode = new LLNode<T> (element);
    newNode.setLink(list);
    list = newNode;
    numOfElements++;
}

protected void find(T target)
{
    location = list;
    found = false;

    while(location != null)
    {
        if(location.getInfo().equals(target))
        {
            found = true;
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            previous = location;
            location = location.getLink();
        }
    }
}

public int size()
{
    return numOfElements;
}

public boolean contains(T element)
{
    find(element);
    return found;
}

public boolean remove(T element)
{
    find(element);
    if(found)
    {
        if(list == location)
            list = list.getLink();
        else
            previous.setLink(location.getLink());

        numOfElements++;
    }
    return found;
}
public T get(T element)
{
    find(element);
    if(found)
        return location.getInfo();
    else
        return null;
}

public String toString()
{
    LLNode currNode = list;
    String listString = "List:\n";
    while(currNode != null)
    {
        listString = listString + "  " + currNode.getInfo() + "\n";
        currNode = currNode.getLink();
    }
    return listString;
}
public void reset()
{
    currentPos = list;
}

public T getNext()
{
    T next = currentPos.getInfo();
    if (currentPos.getLink() == null)
        currentPos = list;
    else
        currentPos = currentPos.getLink();
    return next;
}
```

}

My textfile looks like this:

```
Random Name
1024 
Random Ln NY
70 
185
Joe Smith
1025
134 Nowhere Lane New York NY
80 
170
```

I have been trying to read the data like this:

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class PatientApplicationTester {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        PatientList<Patient> list = new PatientList<Patient>();
        try {
            File f = new File("Patients.txt");
            FileReader r = new FileReader(f);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(r);

            String line = null;

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)  {
                System.out.println(line);

        }
        reader.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

}

I know this just reads line by line and then prints it out, im just really confused as to how I would go about reading the data and then adding to the linked list as a Patient object.  Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Please just read up on how to parse out a string in java (most of those values can be put in directly as strings, just height and weight need to be parsed as integers). Once you figure that out, you should be able to create a `Patient` object with the parsed values and add it to your list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your **Patient** class add a contructor it will be used in your main method:

```
public Patient()
{

}
```

In your **PatientApplicationTester** class in the main method replace it with this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws ClassNotFoundException
    {
        PatientList<Patient> list = new PatientList<Patient>();
        try {
            File f = new File("Patients.txt");
            FileReader r = new FileReader(f);
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(r);

            String line = null;
            Patient patient = new Patient(); // create Object use the constructor that I added.
            int i = 1; // this variable is used to know on which line the reader is on
            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null)  
            {
               if(line.trim().equals("")) // if the line is a new line then add the previous patient to the list and create a new patient, re initialize i = 0
               {
                    list.add(patient);
                    patient = new Patient();
                    i = 1;
               }
               else
               {
                    if(i == 1) // on first line of the file set the patients name
                    {
                        patient.set_name(line);
                    }
                    else if(i == 2)//on second line of the file set the patients ID Number
                    {
                        patient.set_patientIDNumber(line);
                    }
                    // add else if for other attributes on other lines
                    i++;
               }    
            }
             list.add(patient);

             reader.close();

        }catch(IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Seperate your patients in the **Patients.txt** file with a new line like below:

```
Random Name
1024 
Random Ln NY
70 
185

Joe Smith
1025
134 Nowhere Lane New York NY
80 
170
```

Finally in your **Patients** Class the setter methods are wrong you need to add the parameters to it for example

```
public void set_name(String name)
{
    this.name = name;
}
```